# How to enable text box on drop down value change in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a textbox disabled by default, and i want to enable it on the drop down onchange() event.

I tried this but not working:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
    Name:
    <input type="text" id="myText" disabled="true">
    <p>Click the button to disable the text field.</p>
    <select onchange="myfunction()">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
    </select>
    <script>
    function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("myText").disabled = false;
    }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

What is the right one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript is case-sensitive language.

The problem in your code is that the function name is mis-spelled

```
onchange="myfunction()"
```

And in javascript(Notice capital `F`)

```
function myFunction() {
```

Change the function name, and then it'll work.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/9uq2ro1s/)

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myText").disabled = false;
}
```

```html
Name:
<input type="text" id="myText" disabled="true">
<p>Click the button to disable the text field.</p>
<select onchange="myFunction()">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>
```

Also, use `addEventListener` to bind events.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/9uq2ro1s/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Symbols in JavaScript are cases sensitive. You've named your function `myFunction`, but try to call it with `myfunction`.

Also, **do not use inline event handlers!** Use `.addEventListener()` in your JavaScript part like so:

```
function enableText() {
    document.getElementById("myText").disabled = false;
}
//                     You'll need to add a class name to your select
document.querySelector('.mySelect').addEventListener('change', enableText);
```

```js
function enableText() {
        document.getElementById("myText").disabled = false;
    }
    //                     You'll need to add a class name to your select
    document.querySelector('.mySelect').addEventListener('change', enableText);
```

```html
Name:
    <input type="text" id="myText" disabled="true">
    <p>Click the button to disable the text field.</p>
    <select class="mySelect">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Why it is not working in my case? running fine in code snippet though

Answer (score 0):

java script is case sensitive language just change function myFunction() to function myfunction()

```js
    function myfunction() {
        document.getElementById("myText").disabled = false;
    }
```

```html
<html>

<body>
    Name:
    <input type="text" id="myText" disabled="true">
    <p>Click the button to disable the text field.</p>
    <select onchange="myfunction()">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
    </select>
   
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: i modified the function name accordingly but not working

Comment: there is nothing wrong in your code u just mis-spelled myfunction to myFunction